# Objective-C Download Manager for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I'm trying to write a library for the iPhone that will only be used internally with my company (at least that is the plan for now), and I'm working on a 'Download Manager'. I can download files without issue, but I would like support for pausing and resuming downloads. Currently I use the `NSURLConnection` class which supports starting and completely canceling downloads, but I can change that if it turns out that it doesn't support pausing/resuming.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to code your own library? Because there's already a complete and tested library that does what you want: it's ASIHTTPRequest. http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Not necessarily. I found this link while doing some research on the pause/resume capabilities, but I was not able to ascertain whether the ASIHTTPRequest library supports these capabilities. I would be fine with using this library if it does in fact have this support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out Erica Sadun's Cookbook on Asynchronous downloads [here](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C13-Networking/07-Asynchronous%20Downloads). If you are download large files (200 mb +), there would most likely be a memory crash in which case you would have the save the files as it is being received. For now though, check out the source code.

Comment: This is basically what I already have. This example does seem to have support for pausing and resuming downloads.

Comment: http://surgeworksmobile.com/iphone/how-to-implement-resumable-file-downloads-on-iphone-sdk   shows how to resume a file download.

Comment: Thanks for the new link Kevin. I am checking into this.

Comment: Sure thing. If you have any questions let me know :)

Comment: This works well as long as the server supports the 'range' header. Since almost any download I will be performing should be on my servers, this shouldn't be an issue. Thank you so much for your time!